# second line on my system or python terminal now saying: “ -bash: zzzzz#: command not found“

Tags: python-3.7

I have been trying to `pip install psycopg2` for some time now

- I have just updated to python 3.7.4, before this problem started.
- To set my path to a specific python version I used the code below.

`nano .bash_profile`

I thought that it would now be easy for my system to identify the path of the newly installed python, as to enable it to install `psycopg2`. Then the below started happening.

The second line of system terminal or python terminal is now always showing:

> -bash: zzzzz#: command not found on my terminal

No matter what I type on my terminal, I am always getting `command not found`

Answer (score 0):

This would mean you literally have "zzzzz" somewhere in the bash_profile. Bash is seeing "zzzzz" as just another command to run at startup like the rest of the profile script. As there is nothing in your PATH matching that string, bash reports the issue back to you.

Either remove the extra line from your .bash_profile. *OR* use a terribly wasteful work-around!

ln -s /bin/true /bin/zzzzz

This will create a symbolic link to the "true" binary (all it ever does is return true) from zzzzz. Now bash can find zzzzz and run it during start up, which does nothing. No more error and an absurd work around. You should fix the file.